# How to concatenate cell values in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of names in the first column that represent names of sheets. In the next column I need to get the value of a cell from each of these sheets. I've tried to concatenate the string value of the first column and the name of the cell.

I wrote on the cell: `=A2&!&C12` but it didn't work.

Any ideas why not? What am I doing wrong?

Here is an image of what I have done:

[image]

Comment: in excel, there's a `concatenate` function. it's hard to image google docs not having a direct analog.

Answer (score 1):

Sytanx is "=CONCATENATE(A1,A2,A3,"X")"

Here's a good example http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/Productivity/GoogleConcatenate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The error message would go away with the exclamation mark being recognised as text:

```
=A2&"!"&C12
```

However this is unlikely to give you the result you want while C12 in the same sheet is empty. If the content of C12 happened to be `C12` then the result would look like this:

```
Leads Day 1!C12
```

as it would with the C12 cell content anything at all and instead:

```
="'"&A2&"'!C12"
```

but that might not be the result you want either.

Possible adding single quotes so:

```
="'"&A2&"'!"&C12
```

is closer the mark, to result in the appearance:

```
 'Leads Day 1'!C12
```

but if you want say to be able to click on the result to go to Sheet Leads Day 1 and cell C12 there, or use that cell to collect the content of the other cell, that is quite a different matter.